# EF with existing Firebird database model generation problem

Tags: entity-framework-core, firebird, ef-database-first, firebird-.net-provider

I have a `Firebird` database with tables. I need to generate `DbContext`, models etc. So provider installed:

[image: packages]

Connection string is OK:

```
Console.WriteLine("Starting");
FbConnection db = new FbConnection(csb.ToString());
db.Open();
Console.WriteLine($"Database state:{db.State.ToString()}");
```

Db connection is Ok:

[image: result]

Trying to create models using command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "user id=ХХХ;password=ХХХ;database=ХХХ;data source=localhost;port number=3050"FirebirdSql.EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird -OutputDir Models
```

looks good:

[image: command result]

However, DBcontext is empty:

[image: no models]

Comment: Consider asking on the [firebird-net-provider Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-net-provider) as well, you're likely to receive a quicker response there on this specific subject.

Comment: thank's for advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `FirebirdSql.EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird (7.10.1)`. This version doesn't support `DbContext` scaffolding.

Try `version-8.0.0` (currently in alpha3).